# soap fault invalid xml error

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

I am using soap with nodejs. I am getting invalid xml error response. Can any one help?

```
{ Fault:
   { faultcode: 500,
     faultstring: 'Invalid XML',
     detail: 'Error: Attribute without value\nLine: 5\nColumn: 23\nChar: >',
     statusCode: 500 }
}
```